# ThreeJS - Inside A Room - Depth

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like to be able to create a room in ThreeJS.  Here is what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/7oyq4yqz/

```
var camera, scene, renderer, geometry, material, mesh, focus;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    focus = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
    scene.add(camera);
    camera.position.set(0,0,1);
    camera.lookAt(focus);
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    //camera.lookAt(scene.position)

    controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );
    controls.rotateSpeed = 3.0;
    //controls.zoomSpeed = 0;
    //controls.panSpeed = 0.8;

    controls.noZoom = true;
    controls.noPan = true;

    controls.staticMoving = true;
    controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;

    controls.keys = [ 65, 83, 68 ];

    controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );

    geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1000, 1000, 1000 );
    for ( var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i ++ ) {
    geometry.faces[ i ].color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff );
    }
    //material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors });
    material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
    material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.flipSided = true;
    scene.add(mesh);

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: false});
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    render();
}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    controls.update();
    //render();

}

function render() {
    //mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
    //mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;

    //var timer = - new Date().getTime() * 0.0002; 
    //camera.position.x = 1000 * Math.cos( timer );
    //camera.position.z = 1000 * Math.sin( timer );

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

This works, but it doesn't feel like there is much depth (i.e. the walls should feel far away).

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?  I tried looking at the examples and can't figure it out.

Comment: hi why does this interact with the div container? Where is that written could not find that

Comment: Do you know a way to put that room in a div which is like 500x500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the field of view on your camera.

```
THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45
```

Try making that a value between 10 and 180.

Comment: That's very close, thanks.  Any idea how I can make the camera in the center of the "room" and click to drag will turn you around (keeping the horizon stable)